# Как получить диапазон цен? WordPress WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вот мой код минимальная цена правильная а максимум неправильный. Помогите пожалуйста

```
$query = "SELECT MIN(meta_value) as min_price, MAX(meta_value) as max_price
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
      WHERE meta_key = '_price'";

$result = $wpdb->get_row($query);

$min_price = wc_price($result->min_price);
$max_price = wc_price($result->max_price);
```

Comment: ну и? какой максимальный прайс выводится? и какой он в базе?

Comment: Уже все. Сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 0):

проблема в том что в базе лежат строки а не числовые значения

```
$query = "SELECT MIN(CAST(meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS min_price, MAX(CAST(meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS max_price
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
      WHERE meta_key = '_price'";

$result = $wpdb->get_row($query);

$min_price = $result->min_price;
$max_price = $result->max_price;
```